# xmllint not working inside shell script

Tags: xml, linux, shell, unix, xmllint

The following line of code works in my db server ( unix )

```
xmllint --noout CI_PRD_TESTING.XML
```

But the same is not working inside the shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
export FOO="/home/data/others"
echo $FOO
vari=`ls -t1 CI_PRD*.XML | head -1`
xmllint --noout $vari
```

it is giving me the following error. why is it behaving like this...

```
[testuser@mk-testdb others]$ bash validate_xml.sh
/home/data/others
"arning: failed to load external entity "CI_PRD_TESTING.XML
[testuser@mk-testdb others]$
```

Comment: See how the error messages seem to wrap around? You have DOS line-endings in your script. Remove them. See item 1 in the [`bash` tag info wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: @EtanReisner I have removed the cd from the script, still the output is the same.

Comment: You did what? What "cd"?

Comment: @EtanReisner thank you for your advice. I didn't understand your comment "DOS line-endings". Googled it and understood it. went for the dos2unix command. It removed the ^M characters at the end of the script. Now the script is working. with respect to your question "in my script i used  cd $FOO later removed it "

Comment: Ah, ok. For the record, I did point you at a page that spoke about the problem. That's why I included that link.

Comment: @EtanReisner yes you are right. I followed your link only. cat -v validate_xml.sh showed me all the ^M at the end of all the lines in my script. Googled more about the DOS line-endings : ) my 3 hours of hunt comes to an end : D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Million Thanks to Etan Reisner ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner ) for providing me the answer to the question through the comments section itself.

Writing down the answer, just for the sake of others who look for the answers section more than the comments section.

my code was having ^M at the end of each line,

```
export FOO="/home/data/others"^M
echo $FOO^M
vari=`ls -t1 CI_PRD*.XML | head -1`^M
xmllint --noout $vari^M
```

after using the below command, it went out and it worked as expected.

```
dos2unix validate_xml.sh
```